# How does lim $\frac{\ln{ 2^x \over 25^x}}{x} = -\ln \frac{25}{2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln{ 2^x \over 25^x}}{x} = -\ln \frac{25}{2}$$

How is this answer is obtained?

and How would you work this question ?
$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\:\left(\frac{\left(2^n\right)}{25^n}\right)$

thanks

Comment: $\frac{2^n}{25^n}=(\frac{2}{25})^n$.

Comment: It's not only true in the limit. It's true for all positive x. Use the logartihmic identities for division and then powers, cancel the x and use the division identity the other way around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $$\frac{2^x}{25^x} = \left(\frac{2}{25}\right)^x$$

And:

$$\ln \frac{2}{25} = -\ln \frac{25}{2}$$ 
So you don't even need to take the limit.

For the second, again, $\frac{2^n}{25^n}=\left(\frac{2}{25}\right)^n$ and thus it is a geometric series.

Comment: geometric is simpler,thanks, i was using root test...

Answer (score 0):

Just use the $\ln$ rules to simplify: $\ln\frac{2^x}{25^x}=\ln(2^x)-\ln(25^x)=x\ln2-x\ln25=x(\ln2-2\ln5)$ (so $x$ simplifies, and the left hand side is independent of $x$); also $-\ln\frac{25}2=-\ln25+\ln2=\ln2-2\ln5$.